# Setting up JMS queue connection in application to connect to it using Apache Camel

Tags: spring, jms, apache-camel, spring-jms

I have given client's queue connection details to connect to it using Camel. While setting it up in applicationContext.xml, I am stuck at a point.
Client has provided both jndiNames and queue names to connect to these queues. It is something like

```
QueueName
com.requestQueue
com.responseQueue

JNDI Name
comRequestQueue
comResponseQueue
```

During POC, I have just given my local queue names to connect to it using Camel. But here I am confused how to use both jndiNames and queueNames in camel configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some details at
http://camel.apache.org/jms
see the section about using different JMS providers, and using JNDI to find connection factory.

There should be plenty of examples you can find with google. Its essnetially how to use Spring JMS with JNDI.